# Problem with Baking Textures

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-baking, baking

I have a problem with baking textures specifically baking a simple emission color for some reason baked texure always is transparent and i don't know why

[image]

Comment: have you created an Image Texture in each material that you want to bake? please tell a bit more

Comment: yes i did made a empty image texture for my material and yes in baking options i set it so that it would bake emission but the place on the image that should have the color is instead transparent.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe share your file (make it as simple as possible): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=PDa2MSYV" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/PDa2MSYV/)

Comment: If you are trying to bake material of "Main model" to "3d Shading" object you have to enable "Selected to Active" and select both objects before Bake.

Comment: no im trying to bake emission color of 3d Shading to the image texture but for some reason it bakes transparent color instead of black color of the emision

Comment: I can't confirm that ... it is black in my 3.4.